# Unable to call method using facade in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, dompdf, laravel-5.1

I want to generate PDF file from a view in laravel 5.1. I'm using https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

But, Im getting following error: Non-static method Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF::loadView() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('invoices.show_invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are namespacing the wrong PDF class.
You are namespacing Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF and try to use this class as "Facade" which is wrong.
So there are two posiible ways to solve your problem:

1. Setting namespace to the facade:

   use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
2. Using alias (only if you add PDF alias to the app.php in the alias section):

   use PDF;

Refrence: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/158

Answer (score 2):

You have most likely just forgotten to add the ServiceProvider and facade lines to your `config/app.php`:

```
'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider',
```

and

```
'PDF' => 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade',
```

Answer (score 1):

> After updating composer, add the ServiceProvider to the providers
>   array in config/app.php
>
> 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider', You can optionally use the facade
>   for shorter code. Add this to your facades:
>
> 'PDF' => 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade',

You will need to register the facade with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

use \ before the PDF, issue solved.

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('invoices.show_invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue a rose due to namespacing the wrong PDF class. To solve the problem, I set namespace to the facade:

`use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;`

as opposed to:

`use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;`

wrongly set by autocomplete function from my IDE.